# How to count the select tag in each row

Tags: jquery

I want to count the select tag in each row. 
I used:

```
alert($('#table tr select').length);
```

sql fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/xs8zfter/
 When I execute this I got 6. But actually I need 3(ie, each row have 3 I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, You need to iterate over tr elements and then find number of select elements in each pf them. Like this:

```
$('#table tr').each(function(){
  alert($(this).find('select').length)
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sv2kuk6s/)**

Answer (score 4):

Then target each row:

```
$('#table tr').each(function() {
   alert($(this).find('select').length);
});
```

This will alert the number 3 twice, because there are 2 rows that have 3 `select` elements each

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xs8zfter/2/)